# WiX project error when opening up solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, wix, wix3.5, votive

I have a solution with a WiX project in it. Everytime I open it I get an error and then the WiX project is displayed as unavailable.

The error is:

> ```
> Setup\Setup.wixproj : error  : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
> ```

If I right click on the project and then select Reload Project it works fine. I've tried reinstalling WiX but I still get the same problem.

My system is:
Windows 7 Professional 64bit
Visual Studio 2010
Wix 3.5

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I too would like to hear of a solution to this issue.

Comment: when the error occurs is there anything in your Output window in Visual Studio?  (Hint: check all categories; ex. Show output from: General)

Comment: Also occurs when opening from command line through devenv.com.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have "Show All Files" enabled on the project, it will cause this behavior. I just filed a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=642714&aid=3299524&group_id=105970) for votive for this issue.

Update: This was fixed in WiX 3.6

Comment: That is indeed it. Have just verified it by turning it on and off and opening the solution. Thanks for raising the bug.

Comment: Wow.  I'll file this one in my "Things I'd never think to check in 100 years" folder.